# My SSD filled up mysteriously; now I can't boot Debian 12

Tags: debian, boot, disk-usage, ssd, certificates

I have a (new) Lenovo notebook and was using Debian 12. 
I was working in a Google Docs file
and suddenly received a message saying that I should empty my SSD
because it was almost full. 
When I opened Disk Management,
it said that I had just 30 GB free (my SSD has approximately 400 GB). 
However, I DIDN'T fill it. 
I looked at Disk Management a day before this,
and it was around 300 GB free.

Now, I can't even boot Debian. 
When I try to boot the OS, I get a black screen with the following message:

```
0.7229931 integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
```

When I was trying to fix the problem,
I accidentally opened the terminal and could log in my user,
and doing that I verified with `df` that my disk was actually full. 
I don't remember how I opened the terminal, and I'm not able to do that again.

I need my notebook for college. 
How can I get back into it?

Comment: You say you "_received a message saying that i should empty my ssd cause it was too full_" - what was the actual error message?

Answer (score 1):

Use ctrl+f2 at login screen to open the terminal. From there login and delete unused stuff.
Check with df -h which fs is full.

Comment: thanks friend, i could open the terminal and investigate where the error was coming from. thanks a lot really, saved my life

Comment: ....and don't forget to run fstrim unless you've got automatic discard configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fsck` tool (file system check) to check for and potentially repair errors on your SSD partition. Also explore folders like `/var/log`, `/tmp`, and your user directories to identify any usually large files or directories taking up space and delete anything unnecessary.

Comment: thanks man, i just found the error was the syslog and user.log files, i cleaned both of them and now im gonna try to find where the error was coming from